# Color point by distance from origin

Tags: python, 3d, pyvista

Here is a Hopf torus created in Python with PyVista:

```
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv

A = 0.44
n = 3
def Gamma(t):
    alpha = np.pi/2 - (np.pi/2-A)*np.cos(n*t)
    beta = t + A*np.sin(2*n*t)
    return np.array([
      np.sin(alpha) * np.cos(beta),
      np.sin(alpha) * np.sin(beta),
      np.cos(alpha)
    ])

def HopfInverse(p, phi):
    return np.array([
      (1+p[2])*np.cos(phi),
      p[0]*np.sin(phi) - p[1]*np.cos(phi), 
      p[0]*np.cos(phi) + p[1]*np.sin(phi),
      (1+p[2])*np.sin(phi)
    ]) / np.sqrt(2*(1+p[2]))

def Stereo(q):
    return 2*q[0:3] / (1-q[3])

def F(t, phi):
    return Stereo(HopfInverse(Gamma(t), phi))

angle = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 300)
angle2 = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 150)
theta, phi = np.meshgrid(angle, angle2)
x, y, z = F(theta, phi)

# Display the mesh
grid = pv.StructuredGrid(x, y, z)
grid.plot(smooth_shading=True)
```

[image]

I would like to add a palette of colors to this surface. The torus is centered at the origin (0,0,0). I would like to have a color in function of the distance to the origin.

With **Matplotlib**, I do:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

A = 0.44
n = 3

......

colorfunction = (X**2+Y**2+Z**2)
norm = mcolors.Normalize(colorfunction.min(),colorfunction.max())

# Display the mesh
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection = '3d')
ax.plot_surface(z, x, y, rstride = 1, cstride = 1, facecolors=cm.jet(norm(colorfunction)))
plt.show()
```

---

## EDIT

I have a solution, but I don't control the colors:

```
grid = pv.StructuredGrid(x, y, z)
grid['Data'] = grid.points
grid.plot(smooth_shading=True, scalars="Data")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a side note, at least to me it's clearer to compute the magnitude of the points yourself and set those as scalars (rather than relying on the magnitude of vector data as scalars for colour mapping, even though this is supported and valid).

What you're missing is just [a choice of colourmap](https://docs.pyvista.org/examples/02-plot/cmap.html). The default, just like with matplotlib, is `viridis`. Instead it seems you want `jet` (although I'd recommend against this; perceptually uniform colourmaps are preferable in most cases for data visualization):

```py
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv

A = 0.44
n = 3
def Gamma(t):
    alpha = np.pi/2 - (np.pi/2-A)*np.cos(n*t)
    beta = t + A*np.sin(2*n*t)
    return np.array([
      np.sin(alpha) * np.cos(beta),
      np.sin(alpha) * np.sin(beta),
      np.cos(alpha)
    ])

def HopfInverse(p, phi):
    return np.array([
      (1+p[2])*np.cos(phi),
      p[0]*np.sin(phi) - p[1]*np.cos(phi),
      p[0]*np.cos(phi) + p[1]*np.sin(phi),
      (1+p[2])*np.sin(phi)
    ]) / np.sqrt(2*(1+p[2]))

def Stereo(q):
    return 2*q[0:3] / (1-q[3])

def F(t, phi):
    return Stereo(HopfInverse(Gamma(t), phi))

angle = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 300)
theta, phi = np.meshgrid(angle, angle)
x, y, z = F(theta, phi)
grid = pv.StructuredGrid(x, y, z)

# convert to PolyData and clean to remove the seam
cleaned_poly = grid.extract_geometry().clean(tolerance=1e-6)

# add distance from origin as scalars
cleaned_poly.point_data['distance'] = np.linalg.norm(cleaned_poly.points, axis=1)
# this also makes these the default scalars

cleaned_poly.plot(smooth_shading=True, cmap='jet')  # but don't use jet if possible
```

[image: Hopf torus with jet colormap for displaying distance of points from the origin]